# Need help setting up Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

A coworker left and he was our Windows server expert. I am now assigned the task of trying to restore a backup of a TFS server on a Windows Dev Ops server and be able to look at the work item data.

I am 100% green to setting up anything in Windows server(I am a Linux guy) and have no help at this time.

I have a Windows server machine running and I think that there is a brand new installation of Azure DevOps server running on it because if I try to run the installation for Azure DevOps server 2020.1 I get a window stating to repair or uninstall it. Is this just installed by default when you bring up a new Windows server instance (the machine was just given to me)??

[image]

I can get to the Server Manager dashboard but have no clue on how to set it up!

[image]

How do I get the machine setup so I can see the ADO screen and play with things like work items.

How do I access that page?

How do I restore the TFS backup that I have from 2017?

How do I perform a new backup if I need to?

Is this a huge task?

Do I need to install anything else? Visual studio? MySQL?

I looked for guides and videos be can not find anything that is easy to follow - Is there a tutorial out there that will help me?

I pushed so hard for setup documentation on anything that is used and cross training but always got the "we will get to that later". GGGRRRRRRRRRRRR - so frustrated!

I want to be able to get to see this :

[image]

Thanks for any help at all and sorry for the rant.

Comment: Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/single-server?view=azure-devops-2020)?

Comment: Review this doc: [Requirements for Azure DevOps on-premises](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020) to know Azure DevOps Server, follow this doc: [Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020) to know upgradation. This tutorial: [Azure DevOps Server 2020 Install Guide](https://www.benday.com/2020/10/19/azure-devops-server-2020-install-guide/) provides detailed steps to install a brand new Azure DevOps Server 2020 instance.